# pros and cons of array extracting methods

Tags: php, arrays

Which method is good to get values from array using in loops.

```
 1. list()
 2. extract()
 3. Normal extracting like $array['id']
```

code snippet:

```
$sel = mysql_query("SELECT id,name from user");
while($get = mysql_fetch_array($sel)){
 //Which one is good
 extract($get);  
 loop($id,$name)=$get;
 $id = $get['id'];
}
```

I like to know pros and cons of these methods. or any other method exists.

Thanks

Comment: Use the tool appropriate for the specific job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extract()` should be used with most care.  But it is perfectly fine if you want to get a *limited set of known* variables from an associative array.

`list()` however is usually unsuited for associative arrays. It's for numerically indexed arrays, and assigns them to local variables. `list()` is sort of equivalent to `extract(array_combine($list_keys, $array_values));`

Finally the normal array access, most common and most advisable if you only need to access a few array entries. Very obviously also preferred most everywhere because it leads to the least conflicts with existing local variables.

Comment: Setting the `extract_type` parameter will give you a *lot* of ways around conflicting variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `extract()` wherever possible (which is most places). It does things to the symbol table that sane languages do not allow.

Between `list()` and explicit array extraction, `list()` is probably preferable, as it's a bit more concise. It requires that you have an ordered array, though, rather than an associative array.